# Antlr differentiating a newline from a \n

Tags: parsing, antlr, antlr4, grammar

Let's say I have the following statement:

```
SELECT "hi\n
there";
```

Notice there is a literal newline in there, and the escape `\n`. The string that antlr4 picks up for me is:

```
String_Literal: "hi\n\nthere"
```

In other words, not differentiating between the literal newline and the `\n` one. Is there a way to differentiate the two, or what's the usual process to do that?

Comment: Maybe share the code you're using to display your String_Literal.   It's quite possible that the first `\n` are the '\' and 'n' characters in your string and that the code you're using to print this out is showing you're actual newline as `\n`

Comment: @Mike: Perhaps he's using the Antlr4 runtime's `Trees.toStringTree`, which adds escapes to strings using `Utils.escapeWhitespace`. That function converts `\t`, `\n` and `\r` to escape sequences, but curiously creates ambiguity by not escaping the escape character. (Here's [Python](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/fcab02cfd0dedd3b091c8758173b14cbbf4178cf/runtime/Java/src/org/antlr/v4/runtime/misc/Utils.java#L61) but afaics, it's the same in all runtimes.)

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that the output you pasted into your question comes from a call to the Antlr4 runtime method `tree.toStringTree(parser)` (or equivalent in whatever target language you've chosen).

That function calls `escapeWhitespace` in the utilities class/module/file, and that function does what it's name suggests: it converts (some) whitespace characters to C-like backslash escape sequences. (Specifically, it handles newline, carriage return, and tab characters.) It does **not** escape backslash characters, which makes its output ambiguous; there's no way to distinguish between the two character escape sequence `\n` and the escaped conversion of a newline character *in the message*.

They are different in the actual character string, because the Antlr4 lexer does not transform the string value of the matched token in any way. That's your responsibility.

In computing, it is very often the case that what you see is *not* what you got. What you see is just what you see, and a lot of computational power has gone into creating that vision for you. By the same token, nothing guarantees that the vision is an unambiguous, or even useful, representation of the actual values. The best you can say for it is that it's probably more useful than trying to read the data as individual bits. (And, indeed, the individual bits are not physical objects either; despite the common refrain, you could completely disassemble a computer and examine it with an arbitrarily powerful microscope, and you will not see a single `1` or `0`.)

That might seem like irrelevant philosophizing, but it has a real consequence: when you're debugging and you see something that makes you think, "that looks wrong", you need to consider two possibilities: maybe the underlying data is incorrect, but may it's the process which rendered the representation which is at fault. In this case, I'd say that the failure of  `escapeWhitespace` to convert backslash characters into pairs of backslashes is a bug, but that's a value judgement on my part. Anyway, the function is not critical to the operation of Antlr4, and you could easily replace it.